# Programmatically access repeatInterval of XML-based Spring task scheduler

Tags: java, spring

I have this task scheduler. My problem is, that I have to read the repeatInterval from a database and have to set it accordingly, which I cannot do with this XML-configuration. How do I access this value in my groupChatNotificationService?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" >
    
    <!-- Handle scheduled event consumers -->

    <bean id="msgScheduledEventConsumersJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="groupChatNotificationService" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="doNotify" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="msgScheduledEventConsumersTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="msgScheduledEventConsumersJob" />

        <!-- 60 seconds -->
        <property name="startDelay" value="60000" />

        <!-- repeat every 60 seconds -->
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="60000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Scheduler -->

    <bean id="mlsScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="msgScheduledEventConsumersTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It would be very easy if i would be using annotation-based schedulers, but I cannot do that because then the doNotify() method will be executed multiple consecutive times (probably problem with loading some app context multiple times). With this xml-based approach, the doNotify() is only executed once, but now i have to inject the repeatInterval from my system property to the job.

Comment: Why would you need to do that programmatically. add `${YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME}` as the value, add `<context:property-placeholder />` to your XML and restart. No need to make it more complex then that.

Comment: I need to read the repeatInterval from the database after application start. That's why I need to set it programmatically i think.

Comment: That is not what you stated in your question, there it is a system property. If you want relevant answers then ask the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to achieve is, you have interval stored in DB, and you want your jobs to be scheduled based on that value in DB.

First possibility is, keep defining the schedule job in your app context (e.g. XML), and make your DB one of your property source which you could get the value from DB and put in the placeholder.  However this is probably too complex and causing big effect to your overall application.

Another approach is, given `SchedulerFactoryBean` is basically creating a Quartz Scheduler for you, you could have your application access the DB to get whatever detail you want, and programmatically creating Quartz `JobDetail` and `Trigger` and add it to the `Scheduler` bean.